# Lesson of Eicha

Tags: lamentations-eicha

Of course it is a poignant account of the destruction of the Temple and Jerusalem, but what deeper message(s) does Eichah teach us?  Other than the testimony it provides, why was it chosen to be read on the night of Tish'ah BeAv?

Answer (score 3):

The Jewish approach to mourning and what to mourn about "Al Eilah Ani Bocheah"

Answer (score 2):

Reading it helps to make the destruction of the Beis Hamikdash more real to us. That, in turn, fuels a stronger desire to do whatever we can to increase our Jewish knowledge and observance, in order to bring it back.